# django forms: default values for bound forms

Tags: django, forms

With this form:

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, initial='Hello world')
```

If I do something like this in the view:

```
form = Form(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
```

Then initial value of name is lost even if request.GET does not contain `name` as key. Is there any workaround? I would like initial values work to bound forms as "default values".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By slightly modifying Gonzalo's solution, this is the right way:

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, initial='Hello world')

    def clean_name(self):
        if not self['name'].html_name in self.data:
            return self.fields['name'].initial
        return self.cleaned_data['name']
```

---

If you need this, you may have a look at django-filter app. I have discovered it quite recently.

Answer (score 5):

`initial` isn't really meant to be used to set *default* values for form fields.
Instead, it's really more a placeholder utility when displaying forms to the user, and won't work well if the field isn't required (like in your example).

What you can do is [define a `clean_<fieldname>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method that checks if there's an empty value for that field and return the default:

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, initial='Hello world')

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if name is None:
            return self.fields['name'].initial
        return name
```

Comment: This is an interesting option but there is a problem with that `if not name:`. What if `name` was set in request.GET but set to empty string. In this case the empty string would get overwritten.

Comment: I thought that's the behavior you wanted, I'm editing my answer to handle that case :-)

Comment: `name` will never be None. Even if `name` is not set in request.GET, `cleaned_data['name']` will be an empty string because name is a CharField. And if `name` is sent as empty string in request.GET, it is anyways an empty string. So, you cannot differentiate between these two cases.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following pattern for setting default values as initial values given for the form-

```
class InitialDefaultForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(InitialDefaultForm, self).clean()
        # if data is not provided for some fields and those fields have an
        # initial value, then set the values to initial value
        for name in self.fields:
            if not self[name].html_name in self.data and self.fields[name].initial is not None:
                cleaned_data[name] = self.fields[name].initial
        return cleaned_data
```

This ensures that all fields which have an initial value and do not get values from user get populated by their initial value.

Answer (score 2):

`request.GET` is a dictionary like object.

`initial` only works in case of unbound form.

Forms have an attribute named `data`. This attribute is provided as first positional argument or as a `data` keyword argument during form initialization.

Bound forms are those in which you provide some data as first argument to the form and unbound form has `data` attribute set as None.

Here in your initialization of form `form=Form(request.GET)`, you are providing the first positional argument, so `data` attribute is being set on the form and it becomes a bound form. This happens even if `request.GET` is an empty dictionary. And since your form becomes a bound form so `initial` of `name` field has no effect on it.

So, In you GET request you should either do:

```
form = Form()
```

and your `initial` of `name` field would be honoured.

Or, if you want to read `name` from request.GET and if its there then want to use it instead of field's initial then have following in your view.

```
name = request.GET.get(name)
form_level_initial = {}
if name:
    form_level_initial['name'] = name
form = Form(initial=form_level_initial)
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention I need the default/initial value to be present in form.cleaned_data after validation if it has not been overwritten by request.GET

Comment: cleaned_data and validation should come into picture on POST request, not on GET. Can you explain a little more about what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Will this work:

```
initial_form_data = {'name': 'Hello World'}   #put all the initial for fields in this dict
initial_form_data.update(request.GET)  #any field available in request.GET will override that field in initial_form_data
form = Form(initial_form_data)
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
```

Comment: This seems like an elegant solution, but in my case it put things like u'' into the form, which then triggered validation errors. :(  I came up with an alternate answer below that gets around this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solutions either didn't work for me or just seemed not very elegant.  The documentation specifies that initial does not work for a bound form, which seems to be the original questioners (and my) use case:

> This is why **initial** values are only displayed for unbound forms. For bound forms, the HTML output will use the bound data.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#initial

My solution is to see if the form should be bound or not:

```
initial = {'status': [Listing.ACTIVE], 'min_price': 123}     # Create default options

if request.method == 'GET':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    if len(request.GET):
        form = ListingSearchForm(request.GET)       # bind the form
    else:
        form = ListingSearchForm(initial=initial)   # if GET is empty, use default form
```

You could also use the other ways of initializing the form (mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers actually does exactly what clime asked for. So here is my solution for the same problem:

```
class LeadsFiltersForm(forms.Form):
    TYPE_CHOICES = Lead.TYPES
    SITE_CHOICES = [(site.id, site.name) for site in Site.objects.all()]

    type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        required=False
    )
    site = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False,
        choices=SITE_CHOICES
    )
    date_from = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m-%d-%Y',], required=False,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Date From'}),
                                initial=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))
    date_to = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m-%d-%Y',], required=False,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Date To'}))

    defaults = {
        'type': [val[0] for val in TYPE_CHOICES],
        'site': [val[0] for val in SITE_CHOICES],
        'date_from': (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y'),
        'date_to': timezone.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    }

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeadsFiltersForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.data = self.defaults.copy()
        for key, val in data.iteritems():
            if not data.get(key):
                continue
            field = self.fields.get(key)
            if field and getattr(field.widget, 'allow_multiple_selected', False):
                self.data[key] = data.getlist(key)
            else:
                self.data[key] = data.get(key)
```