# Django default value not being assigned! django 1.11 python 3.6

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am stuck finding the solution to this issue. I have a model named 'Album' where certain fields need to be assigned default values if not specified manually. After all the research, it feels like all my code is correct, yet default values are not being assigned. Also, this is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow so please bear with my newbieness. Here are all the codes:

models.py file:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank = True, null = True, default = "some_default_artist_name")
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default='some_default_album_name', blank = True, null = True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()
    date_field = models.DateField()
    dt_field = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, default=date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

forms.py file:

```
class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    artist = forms.CharField(required = False)
    album_title = forms.CharField(required = False)
    genre = forms.CharField()
    album_logo = forms.FileField()
    date_field = forms.DateField(widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy'}, format='%d/%m/%Y'))
    dt_field = forms.DateField(required = False, widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy'}, format='%d/%m/%Y'))

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

It is expected that default values be assigned to 'artist', 'album_title' and 'dt_field' when those fields are left blank in the form. None of the fields are being assigned default values and are remaining null unless maually initialized.

views.py:

```
class AlbumCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'music:login'
    form_class = AlbumForm
    redirect_field_name = None
    #fields = '__all__'
    model = Album
    success_message = "Album was created successfully"
```

Also, if this approach is not correct, what could be the correct approach??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: (Solved)**

So for some strange unknown reason the default parameter just does not work but the reply by [dirkgroten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47451680/8995193) did inspire me to follow a different approach to what I was following earlier.

So, here are the new working codes for those stuck in a similar situation as mine:

models.py: (Removed all unnecessary paramters)

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    album_logo = models.FileField()
    date_field = models.DateField()
    dt_field = models.DateField()
```

forms.py: (No Change)

```
class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    artist = forms.CharField(required = False)
    album_title = forms.CharField(required = False)
    genre = forms.CharField()
    album_logo = forms.FileField()
    date_field = forms.DateField(widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy'}, format='%d/%m/%Y'))
    dt_field = forms.DateField(required = False, widget = forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'dd/mm/yyyy'}, format='%d/%m/%Y'))

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'
```

and finally views.py: (overriding the def_valid method from CreateView )

```
class AlbumCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'music:login'
    model = Album
    form_class = AlbumForm
    redirect_field_name = None      
    success_message = "Album was created successfully"

    def date_in_range(self, x):    #basic function to check if a date is within a date range. Returns True if date is within the date range else false.
        start = date(2000, 12, 31)
        end = date(2017, 12, 31)
        if start <= end:
            return start <= x <= end
        else:
            return start <= x or x <= end


    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        if not obj.artist:    #if artist field left blank, assign this value
            obj.artist = 'Default_artist_name'
        if not obj.dt_field:    #if dt_field left blank, assign this value
            obj.dt_field = date.today()
        if not self.date_in_range(obj.dt_field):    #if entered date is not in range, then display a field error for dt_field.
            form.add_error('dt_field', 'Date out of range')
            return super(AlbumCreate, self).form_invalid(form)
        self.object = form.save()
        return super(AlbumCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Also, any suggestions or feedback is always welcome. Thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because since your model allows for `blank=True` there's no reason for Django to assign the default value. If you want your models to always contain the default value when not specified, don't set your fields to `blank=True`. Also, don't use `null=True` on a `CharField`, as this will allow for two *empty* representations in the database. So you have two options:

1. Change your model:

   ```
   artist = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="some_default_artist_name")
   ```
2. Assign the default value during form validation:

   ```
    def clean_artist(self):
         if not self.cleaned_data.get('artist'):
              cleaned_data['artist'] = "default_artist_name"
   ```

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026479/django-forms-default-values-for-bound-forms).